# How to remove recently dropped element on jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I would like to know how can I remove recently dropped element on jQuery ui.

So far i've got this:

```
$("#trash").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    var id = draggable.attr("id");

    // AJAX VALIDATING IF IT SHOULD LET DROPPED ELEMENT IN TRASH OR NOT

    if (yes){
        // NO PROBLEM
    }
    if (no){
        $('#'+id).remove();
    }
});
```

But it just doesnt seem to remove on this event.

My question is, is there any nother event I could use to delete the element or is there any way to delete it once i've just dropped it?

Comment: can you show your html?
$(draggable).remove() may work

Comment: Actually I also tried to remove all elements with the same class like $('.mydraggableclass').remove(); and all of the elements remove except the one I just dragged. Its very odd.

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? If not, please post your html so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: $(".mydraggableclass").on('mouseup',function(){
    $(this).draggable('destroy');
    $(this).remove();
  })